# Can a magnetic board become weaker if there are many magnets attached to it?

Tags: magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism, popular-science

I have a magnetic whiteboard where I put my travel magnets. I have a plenty of magnets and I am under impression that magnets don't stick as well to the board as they used to when there were just a couple of magnets.

Can such a magnetic whiteboard get weaker when many magnets are attached to it or it's just my impression?

Comment: Does this help? @ https://www.themagnetshop.co.uk/magnetic-whiteboards/

Comment: Or this @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_whiteboard#Operation_of_an_electromagnetic_pen-based_interactive_whiteboard

Comment: Multiple magnets places next to each other (with alternating N/S poles attached to the board) should make the force stronger, not weaker. The problem is that your magnets may not be reversible.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a **weakening of magnets** (they all interact with each other's magnetic fields). It could also be that the whiteboard is **magnetically saturated** (it has reached its maximum limit) but this would require a large strength or a large number of magnets. This second scenario seems unlikely if the board is strong. It is more likely that it is **surface contamination** of the whiteboard or the first scenario (weak magnets)